# How to put SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.myTable ON statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, identity-insert

What I need to do is have a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.myTable ON` statement, what's the syntax of using the above statement in a c# app?

Comment: To whomever marked this as "not a real question" - please read the [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I did wonder why someone had "not a real question"'d it too :-/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's just the same as any other bit of SQL:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Connection String here"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON; INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IdentityColumn) VALUES (@identityColumnValue); SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF;";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identityColumnValue", 3);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if it's part of a `SqlCommand` instance, you just add it to the text:

```
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON";
    cmd.CommandText += //set the rest of your command here.
}
```

I question the necessity of this, however.  If you're inserting an identity into a table with enough frequency that you're using code, I would recommend a stored procedure to do your insert.  You'd then call it basically the same way:

```
using(SqlConnection myConnectino = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_insert_record_into_my_table [ParamList]";
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure;
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaargh, stored procedures with "usp_" prefixed, my eyes, my eyes, it burrrrrrns! ;)

Comment: @Rob - yeah, I know, old convention.  I actually like it because it's easier to find within the management studio (for me).  It serves no other purpose.  If you _really_ want, I guess I can change it.  Just for you. :P

Comment: Meh - long as it isn't "sp_", see: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/don-t-start-your-procedures-with-sp_