# I can not make the registration of users

Tags: c#

Good afternoon!

I am Fabiano. At first my English is bad. I'm using an online translator.
I have a project for my CBT at the University. The problem is that the SQL Server calls an explicit value as the IDENTITY_INSERT is off. How to solve it? See the image...

[image]

And the project is for Windows Desktop.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. The programming language is C #.
Right now, I'm very grateful.

Comment: You might want to explain a little more about the problem, add some code snippets and translate the error text to English (since it's in spanish).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put SET IDENTITY\_INSERT dbo.myTable ON statement in my C# app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373037/how-to-put-set-identity-insert-dbo-mytable-on-statement-in-my-c-sharp-app)

Comment: @YotamSalmon it's Portuguese, not Spanish. I agree with your comment though... The OP error says "it was not possible to register you: it is not possible to insert a specific value for an identity column in the table TbLogin when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to off"

Comment: Oh, sorry for the mistake, and thanks for the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `OFF` (it is default value).
 If you are intentionally trying to insert value into `Identity` column, then you have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` with following command.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TbLogin ON
```

Comment: How? Where? You should not just paste some code without giving a description of where/how to use it.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Like following ? Open up Sql Server Management Studio, Create new Query ,  paste following code and press Execute. how would you explain ?

Comment: You could explain why this needs to be done, and how to do it directly in C# (using the statement as part of the insert query)

Comment: @cFrozenDeath is it ok ?