# SET IDENTITY_INSERT usage in C#

Tags: c#, sql

In a C# program I need to copy data from my database to a 3rd party database. I am generating a customer number and inserting that (with other data) into the 3rd party database.

I am the only person writing to that table. Their database is already built and they can't/won't rebuild the table. So, they have an auto increment set up on their table (`qbCUST`). I need to bypass this.

I have found the following post [How to put SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.myTable ON statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373037/how-to-put-set-identity-insert-dbo-mytable-on-statement). I am a bit unclear on the usage.  The accepted anwser is this code snippet:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Connection String here"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON; INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IdentityColumn) VALUES (@identityColumnValue); SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF;";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identityColumnValue", 3);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Should I not be turning identity insert OFF first?

Comment: No, `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` means that you _can_ insert IDs into autoincremented key columns, `OFF` means you _can not_.

Comment: Do not forget to use CHECKIDENT to reseed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON` means that *you* are taking control of the `IDENTITY`; setting it `OFF` means that you are handing control back the database. It is correct as written. The default is `OFF` which means that you **cannot** insert into `IDENTITY` columns.

Comment: Good man.  Thanks.  I will accept the answer when the timer allows.